# I can't remove root terminal

Tags: command-line, unity, apt, bash, launcher

I tried `apt-get remove root terminal`  it says it can't locate it.  Also it doesn't show up in dash.  I also tried:

`sudo apt-get --purge remove root terminal`  .

I tried `locate root terminal` but couldn't find it.  I did `which root terminal` but no output.  I want it gone because everytime I press `control alt t` it launches terminator, but with the root terminal icon in launcher highlighted instead of the terminator icon in launcher which remains unhighlighted.

Also I don't have the root terminal icon on the launchpad, but it launches (and the icon appears on the launcher highlighted) when I press `control alt t`

Comment: `root terminal` is not a program. It's not even a valid program name, because it has a space in the middle. Do you mean `gnome-terminal`? Please [edit your question](http://askubuntu.com/posts/850173/edit) to clarify. Maybe a screenshot would help.

Comment: You don't want to remove that terminal app, even if I told you how. It is used a lot, especially during system troubleshooting, configuration, and editing system files. What is the REAL problem that you're trying to solve? control-alt-t does launch the standard terminal program. You'll have to see if terminator can be launched by adding a custom shortcut in the keyboard system settings panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no program named `root terminal`. It is just regular terminal with root privileges.

When you tried `locate root terminal`, it considered `root` and `terminal` to be separate arguments and probably showed results for anything similar to `root`.

I think you might want to configure your keyboard shortcuts. Open the keyboard shortcuts section in System Settings, and disable the existing terminal shortcut. Then set up a custom shortcut for your terminal, and set it as Ctrl+Alt+T.